# For some reason I don't have an 'Automatically Add to iTunes' folder. Is that normal?

Tags: itunes, macos

I'm reading that a lot of people have this folder under their `~/Music/iTunes/` folder called `Automatically Add to iTunes` that lets them put files in and have iTunes reorganize them within the library and remove them.

I don't have this folder for some reason. Here's my command line list of files in that folder:

```
[teddyknox@teddyknox iTunes]$ ls -la
total 47960
drwxr-xr-x+ 14 teddyknox  staff       476 Dec 19 12:10 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 12 teddyknox  staff       408 Dec 17 16:44 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 teddyknox  staff     12292 Dec 19 10:44 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x+  6 teddyknox  staff       204 Nov 30 10:15 Album Artwork
drwxr-xr-x+ 10 teddyknox  staff       340 Mar 31  2012 Mobile Applications
drwxr-xr-x+ 13 teddyknox  staff       442 Nov 30 10:14 Previous iTunes Libraries
-rw-r--r--+  1 teddyknox  staff    538607 Dec 20  2011 Temp File.tmp
-rw-r--r--+  1 teddyknox  staff   3685049 Dec 20  2011 iT.tmp
-rw-r--r--+  1 teddyknox  staff    172032 Dec 19 10:26 iTunes Library Extras.itdb
-rw-r--r--+  1 teddyknox  staff    528384 Nov 30 10:14 iTunes Library Genius.itdb
-rw-r--r--@  1 teddyknox  staff   4022157 Dec 19 12:10 iTunes Library.itl
lrwxr-xr-x   1 teddyknox  staff        56 Sep 13 19:37 iTunes Media ->       /Volumes/root/Users/teddyknox/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/
-rw-r--r--@  1 teddyknox  staff  15579060 Dec 19 12:10 iTunes Music Library.xml
-rw-r--r--@  1 teddyknox  staff         8 Dec 19 10:26 sentinel
[teddyknox@teddyknox iTunes]$ pwd
/Users/teddyknox/Music/iTunes
```

I've tried manually adding a folder with that name and restarting iTunes, but the process still doesn't work.

Why am I missing this folder, and what I can I do to get it in place and working OK?

Comment: Also running 10.8.2 with the latest version of iTunes (11.0.1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s in the iTunes Media folder, no?

```
iTunes Media % pwd                                                                                                                                                                
/Users/paul/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media
iTunes Media % ls -la                                                                                                                                                                          total 8
drwxr-xr-x   6 paul  staff  204 31 Oct 10:37 .
drwxr-xr-x  11 paul  staff  374 19 Dec 16:37 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 paul  staff  305 20 Aug  2010 .iTunes Preferences.plist
drwxr-xr-x   2 paul  staff   68 20 Aug  2010 Automatically Add to iTunes
drwxr-xr-x   7 paul  staff  238 31 Oct 11:21 Mobile Applications
drwxr-xr-x   4 paul  staff  136  5 Jan  2012 Music
```

Comment: Turns out I had accidentally placed a bunch of music folders inside `iTunes\ Media` so it was hidden in plain sight. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: In my case it is in `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Music`